# How do I add a count of related records in CakePhp index

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am working on an application to store records for a youth group.

This youth group has a system of badges for members to achieve and I have the following tables;

members
badges
member_badges

The first two tables are self explanatory, members are the youth group members and the badges is the name of a badge, eg. FieldCraft, Life Saving, First Aid and so on.

The member_badges records the achievement of a member and will have the member_id, badge_id, date of attempt and status (Pass or Fail). We record failed attempts to as it will help us to gauge the effectiveness of a course - what's the pass rate and so on.

I want to create a table with the following data;

Badge | Number of Attempts | Pass | Fail

I've created a badgeController function as follow;

```
public function badgereportsummary() {

    $paginate = array(
        'contain' => array('MemberBadge'));

    $this->Paginator->settings = $paginate;
    $this->set('badges', $this->paginate());
}
```

Now this works in a fashion - it returns an array of Badges, each of which contains an array of the Member Badges and I've got a rough and ready page work with the following in the View

```
echo h(count($badge['MemberBadge']));
```

However - this won't allow me to sort on this field, and also in future I want to add the ability to limit on a date range e.g. "Show me the count of First Aid badges attempted from 1/1/15 through 30/3/15". I've seen some suggestions online about using counterCache (I've used that in other places on the app) but this won't allow me to work out count for date range etc.

What I think I want to to is add the count of the Member Badges on a particular page as a virtual field in the controller. I've been searching the docs and Google, and beating my head on the keyboard all day and can't work it out. Any suggestions on how to accomplishment this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Sorry - thought I'd added in tags.

CakePHP 2.5.2 and MySQL DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your summary report (*Badge* | *Number of Attempts* | *Pass* | *Fail*) looks like it needs a SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT badge.description AS Badge
  , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfAttempts
  , SUM(IF(member_badges.status = 'Fail',0,1)) AS Fails 
  , SUM(IF(member_badges.status = 'Pass',0,1)) AS Passes 
FROM member_badges
JOIN badges ON badges.id = member_badges.badge_id
WHERE member_badges.date_of_attempt BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20140131'
GROUP BY badge.description
ORDER BY NumberOfAttempts DESC;
```

I would then change your **badgereportsummary** method to generate this SQL, which is relatively straightforward.

1. Move the function from the Badge controller model to the MemberBadge model
2. Create virtual fields for the new column names within the method ->

   1. `$this->MemberBadge->virtualFields['NumberOfAttempts'] = 0;`
   2. `$this->MemberBadge->virtualFields['Fails'] = 0;`
   3. `$this->MemberBadge->virtualFields['Passes'] = 0;`
3. Write the find:

Code Example

```
$fields = array('Badge.description'
                ,'COUNT(*) AS MemberBadge__NumberOfAttempts'
                ,'SUM(IF(MemberBadge.status = 'Fail',0,1)) AS MemberBadge__Fails' 
                ,'SUM(IF(MemberBadge.status = 'Pass',0,1)) AS MemberBadge__Passes');
return $this->find('all'
       ,'conditions' => array('MemberBadge.date_of_attempt BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($start_date,$end_date)
       ,'fields' => $fields
       ,'order' => array('NumberOfAttempts DESC')
       ,'group' => array('Badge.description'));
```

Then in any Badge controller method call `$this->Badge->MemberBadge-> badgereportsummary($start_date, $end_date)`

I would not use a *permanent* virtual field (i.e., defining the virtual field in the model) since this is an aggregate function. Also, I would not go with counterCache for your exact reason - needing to filter the results based on another field.

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty much worked a treat!

My mistake was in basing it on the Badge Controller - really I needed MemberBadges. Thanks for the suggestions